# Proper fullscreen resizing windows and linux C++

Tags: c++, winapi, fullscreen, x11

I am using win32 API and x11 for my engine I am writing. It is a game engine and of course it needs the ability to create a fullscreen window with best resolution. Currently, I manage to do that on windows, but I tried on other computers and it seems that sometimes the window starts outside the monitor or ends outside it, so my method is unreliable. What I do is changing the resolution to a certain supported resolution I chose before (all done programmatically in C++), which works nicely on my dev computer but not necessarily on others. In many games I have seen, the best resolution is chosen automatically. How does that happen? Is there a special function in windows to choose the best game resolution? I dont know how I should handle this issue.
The same goes on for linux, where I do not have anything at all. Could somebody show me how to create a fullscreen window with x11/xfree86 or sth? I know the headers but not the code. Thanks for your time.

BTW I used to create a fullscreen window by getting the desktop resolution dimensions and simply resizing the window to these dimensions, which worked very well and is reliable. However, most games (even professional games like bf4) always change the resolution before starting the game. Is there a reason for that? Maybe performance (buffer size?)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ including a whole API for one function is a __real__ overkill. You __should__ read the question before commenting that way. Really.

Comment: @PawełStawarz At least I mentioned that I didn't read it, and why ...

Comment: OK, I see, thanks for understanding me, but for the others to note: I don't want to use Qt or GTK or anything like that for my engine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that doesn't make your comment any better. I would expect a person with such reputation to know how to behave towards people asking questions they really thought over and did research on.

Comment: @PawełStawarz 1. Format and highlighting the important points matters for judging a questions quality 2. The OP didn't state anything in their question that using an appropriate GUI framework isn't an option 3. I made a suggestion: _You **may** want_ Seriously, I don't get what should be wrong with my comment, that's what's the SE feature s made for.

Comment: If you're doing a game, just use SDL. It will take care of all the platform specific **** for you, so you can focus on the important stuff. It just isn't worth the time learning WINAPI/X11/Wayland/MIR/whatever MacOSX uses. Not even for educational purposes, IMHO.

Comment: That what many people say, but I want to write my own engine even if it is reinventing the wheel. Somebody should know how it works internally?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about "real" fullscreen like popular PC games as Battlefield and Call of Duty etc uses, then you must first understand that these kinds of games don't just use a Window large enough to cover the viewport. With "real" fullscreen the resolution may change also the number of colors available to suit your needs - it actually takes over the whole viewport and screen and does not interact with the regular Windows UI.

[Windows tutorial using DirectX for "real" fullscreen](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-4-4)

[Linux tutorial using OpenGL GLUT for "real" fullscreen](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/fullscreen.html)

Comment: Oh, I should have been a bit more clear: I used to do the "fake" fullscreen, but now I did change it (I use OpenGL btw) as I stated in my question. The thing is that this real fullscreen has unexpected effects on different computers, so my question is are there more things to worry about? Do I have to worry about monitor positions etc? I read somewhere that the monitor doesn't necessarily start at (0,0)